# How to use the `rule` mark in vega

Tags: javascript, visualization, data-visualization, vega

I'm having trouble using the `rule` mark in vega to create lines that span the entire width or height of a plot.

The [documentation for `rule`](https://github.com/vega/vega/wiki/Marks#rule) is a bit sparse. I'm basing my example below on [this google groups post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vega-js/vfacmbp-yLU/J9zPm4o44_kJ).

```
{
  "width": 250,
  "height": 250,
  "padding": "auto",
  "scales": [
    {"name": "xscale", "type": "linear", "range": "width", "domain": [0, 10]},
    {"name": "yscale", "type": "linear", "range": "height", "domain": [0, 10]}
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"type": "x", "scale": "xscale"},
    {"type": "y", "scale": "yscale"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rule",
      "properties": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "value": 0},
          "x2": {"scale": "xscale", "group": "width"},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 5.5},
          "stroke": {"value": "green"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Seems straight-forward enough, but I'm getting an empty plot in the [vega editor](https://vega.github.io/vega-editor/?mode=vega)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is width the specification of `x2`.

In this case it should be either:

```
"x2": {"scale": "xscale", "value": 10},
```

or

```
"x2": {"signal": "width"},
```

Making the full specification:

```
{
  "width": 250,
  "height": 250,
  "padding": "auto",
  "scales": [
    {"name": "xscale", "type": "linear", "range": "width", "domain": [0, 10]},
    {"name": "yscale", "type": "linear", "range": "height", "domain": [0, 10]}
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"type": "x", "scale": "xscale"},
    {"type": "y", "scale": "yscale"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rule",
      "properties": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "value": 0},
          "x2": {"signal": "width"},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 5.5},
          "stroke": {"value": "green"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]